# Can I completely disable an audio device in OS X?

Tags: macos

I have two Thunderbolt Displays plugged into my laptop, and as a consequence, two additional audio devices become available. I find that even when I configure one display as the default output and input device, the actual behavior I get is usually unpredictable and rarely reflects the configuration I set.

I will never use the mic or audio on one of the displays. Can I somehow delete the device or otherwise deactivate it from OS X? Some sort of equivalent effect to what you get in Windows when you go to Device Manager, right-click the device, and selecting "Disable" (or whatever the text is, going from memory here)? Maybe a plist I can edit somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Disabling a device can't be done from Audio MIDI Setup :(

Someone suggested https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/ which can do it (not my discovery). In typical Mac fashion this feature isn't free.

Comment: SoundSource cannot do this either

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before but my mac isn't in front of me right now to double check. In the utilities folder is an application Audio MIDI Setup. There I believe you can disable audio devices.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that utility. I've used that to make some audio configuration changes before, taking a look now...

Comment: So it does indeed list all available audio devices, and I do see the standard + and - buttons below the list for adding/removing items. However, when I select a device (any device listed, in my case) the - button is greyed out.

Comment: This is hella frustrating. I am on Big Sur. And my Samsung U32J59x monitor always steals sound output when I wake my Mac from sleep. However, that monitor doesn't have speakers. So I always have to manually switch audio back to my Internal Speakers to get any audio.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thread at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285311/how-to-stop-sound-output-switching-to-a-monitor-when-it-gets-plugged-in

One of the [advice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373208/320660) from there seem working to solve your use case: There is an [Audio Profile Manager](https://apps.apple.com/ie/app/audio-profile-manager/id1484150558?mt=12) which allows you to pin the device, so preferred devices stay selected when unplugging & re-plugging them.